# angular material2 change button color when clicked

Tags: angular5, angular-material2

I want to change a material mat-mini-fab button's color the when button is clicked.

My attempt is like below. But doesn't work.

```
<button mat-mini-fab color="primary" #btn>Btn</button>

@ViewChild('btn') btn: ElementRef;
clicked() {
    this.btn.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#5789D8';
    this.btn.nativeElement.style.color = '#FFFFFF';
}
```

Comment: thank you mr. Ron to fix my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `[ngClass]` to dynamically toggle a css class on click

`<button [ngClass]="{'test': newColor}" (click)="toggleColor()" mat-fab>Primary</button>`

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpq7bk)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I wanted to do.